# org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/RefreshBootstrapRegistryInitializer error when Spring Boot application in Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Jenkins to build my Spring Boot application and then the image is deployed in a Kubernetes cluster.
Application is built using java 8 and the cluster also is java 8
But I get this bellow error

it says "compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0)" but the build was using java 8.

Spring boot version - 2.5.5

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.BootstrapRegistryInitializer : org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.RefreshBootstrapRegistryInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:475)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:457)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getBootstrapRegistryInitializersFromSpringFactories(SpringApplication.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:285)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.adl.et.telco.dte.celcom.reportmgt.ReportMgtServiceApplication.main(ReportMgtServiceApplication.java:55)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/RefreshBootstrapRegistryInitializer has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:757)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:468)
    ... 16 more
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check again if your Jenkins is really using Java 8 when building your project.

Also, specify maven compiler source and target version to Java 8 in project's `pom.xml`.

Either add the properties in `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

or configure maven compiler plugin:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Please see this [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for more details. Hope it helps!